# stmp and imap send and fetch

Tags: swift, macos, email, smtp, imap

I'd like to make a simple program to send and fetch emails from selected email. Is there any simple methods of doing that? I searched, and found a couple of examples like https://developer.ibm.com/swift/2017/05/31/4675/ , but is there any way to simplify that? (to simplify code to up couple of functions or use only basics of that? Instead of loading frameworks, or loading only needed elements?) It's for Mac OS X prog. 
Main question is is it possible to simplify this process and how to fetch email (one or more) from server back to app or something similar.

Is there any MessageUI equivalent for mac os?

Comment: The example you show is for a swift server side project and not macOS program. So which are you really wanting to develop for?

Comment: I need to create macOS program, the earlier link provided was one of examples I found. I just can't find anything specific for macOS. There are a lot of various ways to do it in iOS (like MessageUI), but I don't see something similar for mac